# .NET Framework generates strange DCOM error

Tags: .net, com, interop, ms-word

I am creating a simple application that enables merging of key-value pairs fields in a Word and/or Excel document. Until this day, the application has worked out just fine. I am using the latest version of .NET Framework 4.0 (since it provides a nice wrapper API for Interop). My sample merging method looks like this:

```
public byte[] ProcessWordDocument(string path, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvs)
{
  logger.InfoFormat("ProcessWordDocument: path = {0}", path);
  var localWordapp = new Word.Application();
  localWordapp.Visible = false;
  Word.Document doc = null;
  try
  {
    doc = localWordapp.Documents.Open(path, ReadOnly: false);
    logger.Debug("Executing Find->Replace...");
    foreach (Word.Range r in doc.StoryRanges)
    {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in kvs)
      {
        r.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll,
            FindText: kv.Key,
            ReplaceWith: kv.Value, Wrap: Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue);
      }
    }
    logger.Debug("Done! Saving document and cleaning up");
    doc.Save();
    doc.Close();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    localWordapp.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(localWordapp);
    logger.Debug("Done.");
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // Logging...
    // doc.Close();
    if (doc != null)
    {
      doc.Close();
      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    }
    localWordapp.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(localWordapp);
    throw;
  }
}
```

The above C# snippet has worked all fine (compiled and deployed unto a Windows Server 2008 x64) with latest updates installed. But now, suddenly, I get the following strange error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at Meeho.Integration.OfficeHelper.ProcessWordDocument(String path, List`1 kvs) in C:\meeho\src\webservices\Meeho.Integration\OfficeHelper.cs:line 30
   at Meeho.IntegrationService.ConvertDocument(Byte[] template, String ext, String[] fields, String[] values) in C:\meeho\src\webservices\MeehoService\IntegrationService.asmx.cs:line 49

--
I googled the COM error, but it returns nothing of particular value. I even gave the right permissions for the COM dll's using mmc -32, where I allocated the Word and Excel documents respectively and set the execution rights to the Administrator. I could not, however, locate the dll's by the exact COM CLSID given above. Very frustrating.

Please, please, please help me as the application is currently pulled out of production.

Anders

---

EDIT: output from the Windows event log: 
Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 12.0.6514.5000, time stamp: 0x4a89d533
Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000
Faulting process id: 0x720
Faulting application start time: 0x01cac571c4f82a7b
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE
Faulting module path: unknown
Report Id: 041dd5f9-3165-11df-b96a-0025643cefe6

- 
   
  1000 
  2 
  100 
  0x80000000000000 
   
  2963 
  Application 
  meeho3 
   
  
- 
  WINWORD.EXE 
  12.0.6514.5000 
  4a89d533 
  unknown 
  0.0.0.0 
  00000000 
  c0000005 
  00000000 
  720 
  01cac571c4f82a7b 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE 
  unknown 
  041dd5f9-3165-11df-b96a-0025643cefe6

Comment: Anything in the windwows event log?

Comment: Hello. I added the output from the Windows Event Log above.

Comment: Just a thought. Is word and excel etc still working correctly? Does it need reinstalling?

Comment: Work is not working properly either. Starting it manually yields the following: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX
  Application Name: WINWORD.EXE
  Application Version: 12.0.6514.5000
  Application Timestamp: 4a89d533
  Fault Module Name: unknown
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Data: 00000008
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID: 1030

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1030
  Brand: Office12Crash
  skulcid: 1030

Comment: Would you recommend reinstalling Word? :/

Comment: Excel generates a similar error (when starting it from the start menu): 
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BEX
  Application Name: EXCEL.EXE
  Application Version: 12.0.6524.5003
  Application Timestamp: 4b4fba46
  Fault Module Name: unknown
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
  Exception Offset: 00000000
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Data: 00000008
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID: 1030

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1030
  Brand: Office12Crash
  skulcid: 1030

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Office 2007 Enterprise Ed. fixed the problem. But what a headache.